# Borrow checker "cannot move out of borrowed content"

Tags: rust

Why can't I do this?

```
pub fn start_workers(&mut self) {
    // start all the worker threads
    self.dispatch_thread = Some(spawn(||{
        for _i in 1..10 {
            println!("Price = {}", 10);
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        }
    }));
    self.dispatch_thread.unwrap().join();
}
```

I'm getting the following error,

> ```
> error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
>    --> src/orderbook.rs:195:9
>     |
> 195 |         self.dispatch_thread.unwrap().join();
>     |         ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
> ```

Comment: thank you for the formatting correcction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed a non-obvious error message. Have a look at the method signatures for [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap):

```
pub fn unwrap(self) -> T
```

and [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take):

```
pub fn take(&mut self) -> Option<T>
```

`unwrap` consumes the `Option` (note the receiver is `self`), which would leave `self.dispatch_thread` in an unknown state. If you use `take` it is returned to the `None` state as you probably intended.

You probably want `take` in this context; as shown here:

```
use std::thread;
use std::time;

struct Foo {
    foo: Option<thread::JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn nope(&mut self) {
        self.foo = Some(thread::spawn(|| {
            for _i in 1..10 {
                println!("Price = {}", 10);
                thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
            }
        }));
        self.foo.take().unwrap().join();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Some(thread::spawn(|| {
        for _i in 1..10 {
            println!("Price = {}", 10);
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
        }
    }));
    foo.unwrap().join();

    let mut foo = Foo { foo: None };
    foo.foo = Some(thread::spawn(|| {
        for _i in 1..10 {
            println!("Price = {}", 10);
            thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));
        }
    }));
    foo.foo.unwrap().join();

    let mut foo = Foo { foo: None };
    foo.nope();
}
```

Note that `assert!(foo.foo.is_none());` would be similarly illegal; but is valid in this case because we don't violate that constraint. In the method with `&self` as a receiver, this isn't true, which is why it is illegal in that case.

Comment: thanks! it's clearer now!